# Hbase REST API /status/cluster : difference between "text/plain" and "application/json"

Tags: json, rest, hadoop, hbase

First, we get all the result about the regions.

```
text/plain :
% curl http://localhost:8000/status/cluster


application/json :
% curl -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8000/status/cluster
```

But, second, the region name did not match.

which is,

```
"text/plain" is like this: "*content,601292a839b95e50200d8f8767859864,1244869158156*"

"application/json" is like this :"*dXJscyxodHRwfHdlYXRoZXIuYm9zdG9uLmNvbXw4MHxMWU5YL
mpzLDEyNDQ4NTE5OTA4NTk*"
```

how can I **TRANSFER** "*dXJscyxodHRwfHdlYXRoZXIuYm9zdG9uLmNvbXw4MHxMWU5YLmpzLDEyNDQ4NTE5OTA4NTk*" **TO** "*content,601292a839b95e50200d8f8767859864,1244869158156*"

Comment: the curl commands from : https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/rest/package-summary.html

Comment: I guess you can't really get it from that. I think it is the name of the region (here content) encoded to md5. All you can try is to connect the name of your region to this hash...